# Postgresql doesn't accept replication connection

Tags: postgresql, replication

Plain old streaming replication.
PostgreSQL: 9.2.7
Windows 8.1 64 bit

My primary and secondary clusters are on **same** windows machine. I have already done **pg_start_backup()** and everything, so both nodes have exact same data.

Now the problem with replication is "replication connection" from slave server do not connect to primary server but I can connect using same params using psql shell. What I think culprit is the connection string in slave's recovery.conf:

```
primary_conninfo = 'host = 127.0.0.1 port = 5432 user = postgres password = postgres'
```

I tried localhost, 0.0.0.0, lan IP everything but pg log says:

```
 FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", SSL off
```

Now look at my Master's pg_hba.conf:

```
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   trust
host    all             postgres             127.0.0.1/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
hostnossl    all     postgres    127.0.0.1/32    trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

It like I allowed every possible connection yet slave can't connect. Can you do any help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The database name has to be `replication` as `all` does not cover replication connections.

```
host    replication    postgres             127.0.0.1/0               trust
```

The [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) further says:

> The value `replication` specifies that the record matches if a
>   replication connection is requested (note that replication connections
>   do not specify any particular database). Otherwise, this is the name
>   of a specific PostgreSQL database. Multiple database names can be
>   supplied by separating them with commas. A separate file containing
>   database names can be specified by preceding the file name with `@`.

Comment: do we need to create a replication database? or is it in-built??

Comment: It's not inbuilt and you have to setup replication. Here's the reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Comment: Note that this is *not* the case for logical replication.

Answer (score 6):

One other possible solution here that I ran into. If you're doing **logical** replication and you have the DATABASE set to replication, it won't work. It needs to just get a regular parameter. The `replication` parameter is for physical replication, not logical replication.

Man, that one took some work to figure out. I hope this helps!

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more.  I spent hours troubleshooting the wal2json plugin until I found this and this was the right answer for me.  It appears that the wal2json plugin uses logical replication so in order to get their example pg_recvlogical command to work I needed to set the pg_hba.conf to use the 'test' database name instead of the keyword 'replication'

Comment: oh man, i was going crazy on this... thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the line below to `pg_hba.conf` and reloading worked for me. Considering the type is 'local', explicitly specifying an address isn't necessary.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   replication     postgres                                peer
```

And remember to `pg_ctl reload`